# TailwindCSS bg-opacity not working in React

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I am trying to set my Login section's background opacity using `bg-opacity-75`, but when I add that to my className, background color will just disappear. And if I use `opacity-75`, all child-div will be transparent as it should, if I use `opacity-100`, background color will just disappear and only input field is visible, it's kinda wired. In addition, I'm using default `tailwind.config` file with tailwind v2.0.2.

Here's my code:

```
...
        <div className={"h-screen w-screen py-10 lg:w-3/6"}>
            <div
                className={"bg-gray-50 h-full max-w-md rounded-2xl bg-opacity-75 shadow-md mx-auto md:max-w-lg hover:shadow-lg transition-shadow"}>
                <Logo/>
                <Text/>
...
```

I aslo tried inline css, still not working.
[using `bg-opacity-75`(there sholld be a white transparent area behind inputs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c3dd.png)

Comment: this seems to work....  https://play.tailwindcss.com/V3MIFuLzzj   not quite sure if thats what you were doing?

Comment: yes, but when I set `bg-opacity-75`, my colored background will disappear.

Comment: Are you using webpack ? If that's the case try to clear the webpack cache and it will work fine. I encounter this error/bug today.

Comment: It will work, Please check your Webpack configuration and Tailwindcss version in package.json

Answer (score 11):

Just an update for anyone who comes in here:
As of Tailwind CSS version 3, they've updated the way opacity classes work in the new version. The older syntax `bg-opacity-75` is now replaced with a new syntax, and the value is applied directly to the color class itself.

The new syntax appends the opacity value to the color, separated by a slash */*. For example, `bg-gray-800` with `bg-opacity-75` would look like this in the version 3 and up of Tailwind CSS:

```
className={"bg-gray-50/75 h-full max-w-md rounded-2xl shadow-md mx-auto md:max-w-lg hover:shadow-lg transition-shadow"}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

[image]

```
<div class="bg-green-400 h-32">
  <div class="bg-gray-50 h-full w-6/12 mx-auto bg-opacity-50">
    <div>Your Opacity child div here</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

// tailwind.config.js

```
  module.exports = {
    variants: {
      extend: {
        // ...
       backgroundOpacity: ['active'],
      }
    }
  }
```

following the official Documentation : https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/background-opacity

Answer (score -7):

***Opacity***

Use opacity Keyword only, for version 2.2.7 Tails wind

example:

```
<div
className = "opacity-75 bg-red-300">
</div>
```